# TinyMCE toolbar at the top of the page

Tags: tinymce

I have Div with contentEditable on it.

I want TinyMCE toolbar sit at the top of the page at a specific place I mention (may be in a div) which can be used to edit contents in contentEditable div.

Someone tell me how to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but what you intend to make sounds a bit silly.
Why don't you use tinymce as its designed to be?
You can assign a tinymce editor instance to your div and tinymce will take care of everything else

```
tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, div_id);
```